# Struts 2 redirect to same page, no content update

Tags: java, struts2

I'm stuck at a redirect to the same page in struts 2.

The content of the page is dynamic and changes based on some variables. I've got a button that changes some of these variables and after that does a redirect to the same page.
But as you can guess nothing changes on the page, even when I press the refresh button of the page nothing changes.
When I go to some other page and return the content of the page is changed.

Any idea how I can make sure the page changes the moment I push the button ?

```
BusinessReply<List<UiMessage>> reply = new BusinessReply<List<UiMessage>>();
reply = openFileOrchestrator.correctDecisionCMD(userContext, interactionId);

if (!reply.hasMessages()) {
    redirectTo = redirectTo(DECISION_OVERVIEW);
} else {
    ...
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you refresh and nothing on the page changes then you're not doing what you think you are, or you're losing request parameters due to the redirect, or similar.

Comment: then why does it changes when I go to the previous page and return ?

Comment: Post:
1) The interested portion of the Jsp;
2) The interested portion of Struts-config.xml;
3) The whole method of the Action that render the page;
4) The whole method of the Action that update the page;

Comment: Yeah, nothing changes on the page, yeah, the button redirects a page on the client side, uyeah or submit to the server